# While loop doesn't wait for the for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, settimeout

This is a slideshow. `delayLoop` opens and closes containers, which works. The problem is that `myFunc01` doesn't wait for `delayLoop` to fully execute. The `console.log` is only here for me as reference.

The `while` loop only exists so that the `for` loop doesn't end. Can someone help me with my logic or find another way to make the slideshow endless?

```js
function delayLoop() {
  document.getElementById("news-1").style.display = "flex";
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      let u = i - 1;
      document.getElementById("news-" + i).style.display = "flex";
      document.getElementById("news-" + u).style.display = "none";
    }, i * 5000);

  }
}
var myFunc01 = function() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 100) {
    (function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        delayLoop();
        console.log("ok");
      }, 1000 * i)
    })(i++)
  }
};

myFunc01();
```

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous. you need to use promises.

Comment: may i ask how you wouldve implemented it? my knowledge of js isnt strong, im only familiar with php

Comment: some Javascript operations take place asynchronously, think of multitasking. But Stackoverflow is just a place to help people with programming, not an online course, or even an on-demand code service. Start your learning with the Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score -1):

**Update** As pointed out in the comments by @MaBed, a couple of the comments in my original answer were incorrect, clearly had a brain melt moment, or two! Have updated to only include the example implementation.

I would say there are plenty of slideshow implementations on the internet to use instead of rolling your own, so might be worth looking at those.

---

However, given you are rolling your own and learning, consider the following:

I'm assuming you have an element like so:

```html
<div>
  <div class="news showing">
  First slide
  </div>
  <div class="news">
  Second slide
  </div>
  <div class="news">
  Third slide
  </div> 
</div>
```

You could use CSS to control the showing and hiding:

```css
.news {
  display: none
}

.news.showing {
  display: flex
}
```

And then use setInterval, rather than setTimeout (as setTimeout only runs once):

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.news'))
  
  let nextElement
  /**
  * Iterate through the entries, checking if they have the showing class.
  * If they do, remove the class, and grab the next element (this will either be the next in the 
  * array, or the first element if we're already at the last news entry)
  */
  elements.forEach((el, index) => {
    if(Array.from(el.classList).includes("showing")) {
        el.classList.remove('showing') //Remove the class to hide this
      nextElement = elements[index+1]!==undefined ? elements[index+1] : elements[0]//Grab next one
    }  
  });  
  nextElement.classList.add("showing");//Add the showing class to the next one so it shows.
}, 1000)
```

Comment: "Secondly, (...) contents of i inside the function in the setTimeout will always be 1, not 1 then 2 then 3 etc." - this is incorrect. The `i` will change. There is no reason it should be stuck at 1.

Comment: @MaBed, you're correct, I was wrong there, I will update the answer to remove that part and clarify.